# Insert Formula through Data Validation in excel

Tags: excel

In Data validation list I defined formulas: ,=1,5+($B$1/$B$2),=2+($B$1/$B$2)*2,=2,7+($B$1/$B$2)*3 ..... and works well for me because I can see all formulas in dropdown list as they are to choose the appropriate one.

But I prefer to define them in a named range since number of formulas are around 20. Unfortunately I can see only the results instead of formula origins in dropdown list when I define as named range so makes me choose the suitable one impossible.

I wonder whether to see the formulas itself when I defined in named range. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. To see the formulas, you'd have to format them as text in the source cells, but then selecting them from the dropdown won't actually evaluate the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work.

A. Enter the list of the formulas you want to use in a range of your worksheet, one formula per cell, without the equals signs. An example list of formulas:

```
1
5+($B$1/$B$2)
2+($B$1/$B$2)*2
7+($B$1/$B$2)*3
```

B. Create the cell with Data Validation to select from the formula list

C. Use `MATCH` and `CHOOSE` to select which formula you want to use for calculations:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(Formula,FormulaList,0),1,5+($B$1/$B$2),2+($B$1/$B$2)*2,7+($B$1/$B$2)*3)
```

Here `Formula` and `FormulaList are placeholders (or named ranges) for the cell that has the chosen formula and the list of formulas, respectively.

Hope that helps

Comment: Dear Xidgel I tried but have source error. May you expose defining of named ranges (Formula & FormulaList) a bit? Thanks.

Comment: I noticed one error that I used commas as decimal seperator but must be point so multipliers 1.5+,2+,2.7+

Comment: @ZRS `Formula` needs to resolve to the cell where you have the dropdown list, e.g., `Sheet1!$F$2`. `FormulaList` needs to resolve to the range containing the list of formulas, e.g. `Sheet1!$F$3:$F$6`.